# In a Workflow using SharePoint designer 2010 i want to make a condition using if statement

Tags: ifilter

In a Workflow using SharePoint designer 2010 i want to make a condition using if statement and if the condition occurs i want go back to a certain action.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot reverse direction in a workflow, you CAN set the workflow properties to execute on change, where the workflow details run only when the condition is met.  I've also heard of people setting a workflow to "wait" on a specific change (not highly recommended).

If you could provide more details on the conditions of your workflow, I'm sure someone could provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in SPD 2010 Workflows to jump back. You have to create a new action in the if branch.